# How does one create a duplex connection using the ActiveMQ Broker URI?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms, activemq-classic

I'm trying to create a duplex bridge from an TomEE server to an ActiveMQ master broker.

```
  <Resource 
    id="ActiveMQResourceAdapter" 
    type="ActiveMQResourceAdapter">
    BrokerXmlConfig=broker:(vm://localhost,network:static:tcp://localhost:61616)?useJmx=false 
    ServerUrl=vm://localhost?async=true 
  </Resource>
```

This works, but only in one direction.

I suspected the answer would be to do this:

```
  <Resource 
    id="ActiveMQResourceAdapter" 
    type="ActiveMQResourceAdapter">
    BrokerXmlConfig=broker:(vm://localhost,network:(static:tcp://localhost:61616)?duplex=true)?useJmx=false 
    ServerUrl=vm://localhost?async=true 
  </Resource>
```

However that results in a parse error. I feel like I'm missing something obvious. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There  are 2 broker uri supported in tomee:
- broker: direct URI
- xbean (needs active-mq-spring + spring dependencies in tomee/lib)

Last one uses amq.xml syntax as mentionned by Matt but first one uses direct URI.

Duplex was not supported cause AMQ doesn't support network connector configuration through URI, this has been fixed on the coming tomee: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TOMEE-1802

Syntax would be a uri encoded networkConnectorUris (for port 61616 for instance):

```
broker:(tcp://localhost:61616)?networkConnectorURIs=static%3A%2F%2Ftcp%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A61616%3Fduplex%3Dtru
```

Comment: Hey I think you might want to revist this... why is a new parameter: `networkConnectorURIs` needed when you already can configure the network using the activemq url as shown in my second example? This would create two ways to configure the same thing... Really just support for the duplex parameter is all that's needed...

Comment: I think you mix up connector and networkConnector no?

Comment: Nope... `network:/` is what I'm intending to configure... but now that I've looked at the source code, I think this change actually needs to be in AMQ, not TomEE

Comment: not sure what you mean, since TOMEE-1802 you can configure both in tomee

Comment: Why is there two ways to specify the network URLs and which one takes prescedence: `broker:(vm://localhost,network:(static:tcp://localhost:61616)` or `broker:(vm://localhost)?networkConnectorURIs=static%3A%2F%2Ftcp%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A61616`

Answer (score 0):

The BrokerXmlConfig property should be a uri to the location of a valid activemq.xml configuration file. Within the activemq.xml file is where you'd wire up your networkConnectors and any other configuration settings

More details here [ActiveMQ and RA](http://activemq.apache.org/integrating-apache-activemq-with-jboss.html)